Why dynamic page performs requests during build (App router)?
Since a Dynamic page is "server-rendered on demand" why does nextjs performs it's requests during build even though these requests will be performed again when the page is requested?
When i build my application i can see that getData function runs twice and a network request is performed to get the data (i can see 2 incoming requests in Mockoon logs).
I would expect that during build only requests for Static and SSG pages would happen in order to have the pages ready beforehand.
○  (Static)   prerendered as static content
●  (SSG)      prerendered as static HTML (uses getStaticProps)
ƒ  (Dynamic)  server-rendered on demand

I can imagine that if i wanted to cache the getData response (by using fetch) it would make sense to make the request in build time so that when some user requests for the page the data could be retrieved from cache but in my case i don't want that.
src/app/dynamictest/page.tsx
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import Link from "next/link";
import { getDataWithAxios } from "../utils/callHelper";

type MockoonResponse = {
  date: string;
  seo: {
    title: string;
    description: string;
  };
};

async function getData() {
  try {
    // No caching is being used 
    const res = await getDataWithAxios<MockoonResponse>({
      method: "get",
      params: {
        whatever: "123",
      },
      endpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:4003/api/mockoontest",
    });
    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

export async function generateMetadata() {
  const res = await getData();
  return {
    title: res?.seo.title,
    description: res?.seo.description,
  };
}

export default async function Page() {
  const isLoggedIn = cookies().get("access-token");
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return <h2>Just to use cookies in code</h2>;
  }
  const data = await getData();
  return (
    <div>
      <Link href="/">home</Link>
      <h3>I am a dynamic page {data?.date}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}


Problem :

Why dynamic page performs requests during build (App router)?

Possible Cause :

Page is not dynamic because you haven't used export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
Also because this page is not a dynamic route ex. /user/[id] here id is dynamic which makes the page dynamic automatically.
But as you have just a page.tsx in a non dynamic folder, nextjs makes it as static, server-side-rendered because its default behaviour.

Possible Solution :

Add this line at top of the dynamictest/page.tsx
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'


This will make this page dynamic, & prevent it from becoming static.

getData function runs twice :
This can be prevented by using react cache function
Make necessary changes in code as needed & handle error.
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
import { cache } from 'react'

const getData = cache(async () => {
    try 
    {
        const res = await getDataWithAxios<MockoonResponse>({
          method: "get",
          params: {
            whatever: "123",
          },
          endpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:4003/api/mockoontest",
        });
        return res;
    } 
  catch (error) 
  {
    console.error(error);
    return error
  }

})

export async function generateMetadata(){
... // as it is
}

export default async function Page() {
... // as it is
}


Please Read :

Dynamic Routes : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes
Route Segment Config : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config
Example which shows use of cache function : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#example
cache : https://react.dev/reference/react/cache


If you have any doubts, then please leave a comment (I will update answer if necessary)

